# Set Materialize Select drop down value with JS

Tags: javascript, select, materialize

In Materialize framework:

I have a function that updates input box and selects after clicking a button. Works fine on Inputbox but fails with selects:

My select is:

```
<select class="" id="nm" name="nm"><option selected value="Select Product" disabled>Select Product</option><option value="Roulette">Roulette</option><option value="Texas">Texas</option><option value="Pokers">Pokers</option></select>
```

i pass the value "Texas" for variable nm to the function :

```
function editData(id, nm, em, hp, ad) {

   $('#id').val(id);
   $('#nm').val(nm);
    $("#nm").material_select();
    $('#em').val(em);
    $('#hp').val(hp);
    $('#ad').val(ad);
    $('#id').prop("readonly",true);
    $('#save').prop("disabled",true);
    $('#update').prop("disabled",false);

}
```

my select should show "Texas" as default / selected value but it is blank.
I try to refresh it using $("#nm").material_select(); but it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Hello I am using solution without re-initialization. If you want to change your select value in materialize select just use this function:

```
function msValue (selector, value) {
 selector.val(value).closest('.select-wrapper').find('li').removeClass("active").closest('.select-wrapper').find('.select-dropdown').val(value).find('span:contains(' + value + ')').parent().addClass('selected active');
}
```

Then just use

```
msValue($("#select_id"), "value_here")
```

In your case

```
function editData(id, nm, em, hp, ad) {

    $('#id').val(id);
    msValue($('#nm'), nm);
    $('#em').val(em);
    $('#hp').val(hp);
    $('#ad').val(ad);
    $('#id').prop("readonly",true);
    $('#save').prop("disabled",true);
    $('#update').prop("disabled",false);

}
```

Disadvantage: If materialize change the way of select inicialization, this function would not work, so be aware :)